# Maximum no of table we can left join in one MySQL Query?

Tags: php, mysql, database, join, left-join

I want to know in how many tables we can left join (or inner join) in one MySQL query to  execute the query efficiently(good query execution time)?
i have to join 4 tables in my query. whether it will create any problem in future to join 4 table or more table in a same query ?

```
dbQuery('
    SELECT w.*,t.tenant_name,t.tenant_email,ca.caste_name,co.web_cost_duration
    FROM tbl_websites w 
    LEFT JOIN tbl_tenants t 
    ON w.tenant_id = t.tenant_id
    LEFT JOIN tbl_caste ca 
    ON w.website_caste_id = ca.caste_id 
    LEFT JOIN tbl_web_costs co 
    ON w.web_cost_id = co.web_coste_id 
    ORDER BY w.website_title ASC
')
```

Comment: from experience I'd say more than two joins and its gonna be slow unless your tables are ridiculously small

Comment: "to execute the query efficiently(good query execution time)?" is completely subjective. It depends on what data you need to retrieve, how much of it there is, and what "good query execution time" means for your particular case. There is no magic number of joins that is "good" and no magic number where it becomes "bad".

Answer (score 2):

The maximum number of tables that can be referenced in a single join is 61.

Please refer this link : [Click Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/joins-limits.html)

Answer (score 1):

No this is common. even more then ten joins are no problem at all. To speed up the process you need to add foreign indexes on the join-columns like w.tenant_id.

Comment: how can i add foreign indexes in my tables can u explain me with my example ?

Comment: ALTER TABLE tbl_websites
ADD FOREIGN KEY (tenant_id) REFERENCES tbl_tenants(tenant_id); i did this but its giving me error .

Answer (score 1):

The limitations for SQL Server are listed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx)

The number of tables per query is only limited by the amount of available resources.